# Why in mathematical texts the relative order of the top and the bottom tensorial indices is rarely considered?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

In courses on general relativity, I was taught to always track the relative order of top and bottom (contravariant and covariant) tensorial indices. For instance, the first index of the Riemann tensor

$$ R^{\mu}_{ \ \ \nu \alpha \beta} $$

can be moved down using the metric

$$ R_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} = g_{\mu \nu'} R^{\nu'}_{ \ \ \nu \alpha \beta}  $$

and the indices in the resulting tensor have several symmetry properties, which depend on the fact that $\mu$ stands in the first position. However, in mathematical texts the top and the bottom indices are almost universally written in separate orders, like this:

$$ T^{\mu_{1} \mu_{2} \cdots \mu_{k}}_{\nu_{1} \nu_{2} \cdots \nu_{l}} $$

without any comments on at which position an index goes when being moved, despite the fact that mathematicians writing these texts are clearly aware that physicists want to move these indices up and down. So, what happens here? Why mathematicians don't care about the relative order? And why it does not cause them any trouble?

Comment: You can do all of general relativity without ever raising or lowering an single index. Some physicists prefer that approach, and I know I did. Works just fine. That being said, I still respected their order.

Comment: This is not an answer to the stated question. You can do all of general relativity without indices at all, or instead of Einstein's summation you can write down all the sums every single time, so what?

Comment: It's not an answer, which is why I didn't put it in the answer section. And I think you will have to search for a long time to find physicists who prefer to not use Einstein notation at all, but someone who prefers not to raise or lower indices is [readily available on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_). I have only used tensor notation in general relativity, so I don't know what mathematicians think, but if they are like Frederic Schuller here, and don't actually ever raise or lower them, maybe they don't need to care about the order.

Comment: They still do need to care about their order even if they never raise or lower them, unless they want to ignore, for instance, the symmetric properties of the Riemann and Ricci tensors.

Comment: They need to care about the order of the lower indices, and the order of the upper ones, separately. They don't need to care about the order between upper and lower.

Comment: Yes they do. For instance, $R^{\mu}_{ \ \ \nu \alpha \beta }=R^{ \ \ \ \ \  \mu }_{\alpha \beta \ \ \nu}$ (frankly, I am not even sure this is __true__ without lowering the top index)

Comment: $$R^\mu_{\nu\alpha\beta} = g_{\alpha\gamma}g^{\mu\delta}R^\gamma_{\beta\delta\nu}.$$ This is what @Arthur is saying. If you **don't** raise/lower indices, i.e. if you use the metric explicitly, then there is no ambiguity in ignoring the order between upper and lower indices while maintaing the orders of upper indices amongst themselves and lower indices amongst themselves.

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518996/what-is-the-reasoning-need-for-writing-tensor-indices-like-ti-j-k?rq=1) help?

Comment: I prefer to avoid having an interior index be at a different level (up or down) than its neighbors. That said, I do prefer to indicate clearly the order of the indices, up or down.

Comment: @SammyBlack, not quite, because the question is not only about _what_ indices were lowered, as the accepted answer to the linked question explains. For instance, for the Riemann tensor there is no ambiguity in what index you lower, because there is only one option. But it matters for calculations, in which position does the lowered index stand. If the position didn't matter, you could swap any pair of indices at no cost by first moving an index up, and then moving the same index down to a different position. However, I think that clarification by Nicholas Todoroff explains it well enough